# Does the Law of Total Probability work if the sample space is not partitioned?

Tags: probability

I would like to know if the Law of Total Probability can work in a case where the sample space is not partioned, at least, not entirely. Like this:

[image]

In this specific situation, A1, A2 and A3 are disjoint but A4 and A5 are not, in this case, couldn't I calculate the probability of B as:

$$
 \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^3 P(B|A_i)P(A_i)
$$ 
which is the same as
$$ 
P(B) =P(B|A_1)P(A_1)+P(B|A_2)P(A_2)+P(B|A_3)P(A_3)
$$

When I think about it I don't see why that wouldn't be possible. If someone can explain I would be thankful.

Comment: Well in this case it works. But as soon as $B$ hits the overlapping areas it’s not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your formula works - but there's an easy way to see why it does.

Recall 
$$P(B \mid A_i) = \dfrac{P(B \cap A_i)}{P(A_i)}\text{.}$$
It follows, therefore, that
$$P(B \mid A_i)P(A_i) = P(B \cap A_i)\text{.}$$
The Law of Total Probability can thus be rewritten as (assuming *exhaustive* and *disjoint* events $A_1, \dots, A_n$):
$$P(B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(B \cap A_i)\text{.}\tag{*}$$
Now, let's suppose, for the sake of simple notation, that $A_6$ is everything outside of $A_1, A_2, A_3$ in $\Omega$. Since $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_6$ partition $\Omega$, we may write
$$P(B) = P(B \cap A_1) + P(B \cap A_2) + P(B \cap A_3) + P(B \cap A_6)\text{.}$$
Since $B \cap A_6$ is the empty set (i.e., there is no intersection), $P(B \cap A_6) = 0$. Hence
$$\begin{align}
P(B) &= P(B \cap A_1) + P(B \cap A_2) + P(B \cap A_3) \\
&= P(B \mid A_1)P(A_1) + P(B \mid A_2)P(A_2) + P(B \mid A_3)P(A_3)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
To answer your question directly: the Law of Total Probability (*) **requires** that $A_1, \dots, A_n$ partition $\Omega$. It happens to be a coincidence that you can ignore anything outside of $A_1, A_2, A_3$ because $P(B \cap A_6) = 0$.

Comment: Can't you weaken the partition hypothesis but rather ask that $B \subseteq \cup A_i$ instead ?

Answer (score 2):

It works. The quickest way to see it is probably to construct the following partition
$$ B_i = A_i, i \in \{1,2,3\}, $$
$$ B_4 = A_4 \setminus A_5, B_5 = A_5 \setminus A_4, B_6 = A_4 \cap A_5. $$
Once this is done, the $(B_i)_i$ are disjoint, and if you apply the law of total probability with this partition, you will find exactly the formula you thought of (since $B \cap B_i = \emptyset$ for $i > 3$).

This is a general result, if $B$ is included in a subpartition, you can always modify the extra sets this way so that the formula is valid.